# Postgres ignores indexes after upgrade to 9.5

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

We have recently upgraded our OLTP Production DB (2TB) from v9.2.9.21 to 9.5.1.6 using pg_upgrade.

The upgrade went without incident and we have been running for a week, however have found that the optimizer is ignoring indexes on 2 of our largest partitioned tables. (Note: different issue to 38943115, the data migrated with no issues).

The tables are constructed with individual Btree indexes on BIGINT columns, which the optimizer would previously return queries on sub-second. Post-upgrade the queries take up to 16 minutes (unusable for our customers). The partitions are <100GB, with 2-3 partitions per table.

We suspected index corruption and tried adding duplicate indexes and analyzing, however the new indexes are still ignored unless we force using enable_seqscan=no or reduce random_page_cost to 2 (not practical system-wide). The query response times using the new indexes are still appalling (16 minutes).

We have tried increasing effective_cache_size but no effect. The DB is 24x7 so we cannot reindex the tables/ partitions.

The indexes are defined like so:

```
CREATE INDEX table1_column1_index ON table1 USING btree (column1);
CREATE INDEX table1part1_column1_index ON table1 USING btree (column1);
CREATE INDEX table1part2_column1_index ON table1 USING btree (column1);
CREATE INDEX table1part3_column1_index ON table1 USING btree (column1);
```

....And repeats for each subsequent column in the query (the query plan isn't using composite indexes).

Has anyone encountered this or could suggest any further steps?

Comment: do you have autovacuum enabled? Also, did you configure other variables besides effective_cache_size? https://www.pgconfig.org gives a list of relevant parameters and their values based on RAM, etc.

Comment: After upgrade, were all the tables `ANALYZE`d? See [Slow performance after upgrading PostreSQL from 9.1 to 9.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348608/slow-performance-after-upgrading-postresql-from-9-1-to-9-4). Can you post some of your `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` results to see if there are huge miss-estimates?

Comment: Query plans please? Index definitions?

Comment: run `ANALYZE;` in that database and check again.

Comment: Please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output, table and index definitions.

Comment: 9.5 query plan is at https://explain.depesz.com/s/LS3Gk, 9.2 query plan is at https://explain.depesz.com/s/1Hlh. The index definitions are very straightforward

Comment: Ok we found our root issue - there were some tables which had been missed from the initial analyze. We were expecting these table partitions to be picked up by the subsequent auto-vacuum but it seems they weren't.